# How does akka.net restart a remote node if that process crashes?

Tags: akka.net

Suppose that, I have an actor that has a child actor that runs remotely. And suppose that, the child actor's process crashed with an unrecoverable exception like StackOverflowException for some reason or due to a bug.

In this case, how does the parent node in akka.net restart the crashed remote child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't. Child actor lives under a specific address, and if it cannot be resurrected there, it will stay dead. All of the messages directed to it will land in dead letters.

If this is not the case for you, you can always use [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](https://petabridge.com/blog/introduction-to-cluster-sharding-akkadotnet/), which is a higher level abstraction that automatically manages actor lifecycle.

Comment: What are the common ways to resurrect such an actor?

Comment: From what I've seen, Akka community slowly falls back from using remote deployment - the future API ([akka.typed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.6/scala/typed.html)) doesn't even expose such capability. Right now remote deployment is necessary only if you use cluster router pools. If you do, and your actors need to be statefull, Akka.Cluster.Sharding is probably what you want. If your actors can be stateless, then dead of a single actor is not really a problem, as any other routee actor living on any node can pick up its job.

Comment: In my case I am planning some actors that collect data from external peripherals. The only issue is the drivers are not stable and frequently causing the hosting process to fail. These devices are stateless. But some how I need resurrect their hosting process obviously and start listening these devices again in case of a crash. And these crashes are the sole reason I prefer to host them external processes on the same machine.